# EventListener('click') on document prevents other ('click') from working

Tags: javascript

I want to close a search menu (containing numerous elements) by clicking outside of it. For this I made a (onclick) function to open/close it with a link (which works) and a (onclick) function to detect clics outside of it, and close it. Problem is, my 1st function works on its own, but when I put the second one, nothing works. That's what i've got so far:

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            menuframe = document.getElementsByClassName('searchframe')[0];
            e.preventDefault(); // On bloque l'action par défaut de cet événement
            if (!menuframe.classList.contains('displayed')) {
                menuframe.classList.add('displayed');
            } else {
                menuframe.classList.remove('displayed');
                link.blur(); }
        }, false);

        document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var x = document.getElementById.e.target.id,
                menuframe = document.getElementsByClassName('searchframe')[0];
            if (menuframe.classList.contains('displayed') && !menuframe.contains(x))
                menuframe.classList.remove('displayed'); }
        }, false);
```

I assumed it had something to do with event bubbling/capture, tried to mess with true/false and e.stopPropagation(); without success. Or maybe my code is bad, I'm a newbie in JS. I tried googling everything I could think of, and tried various 'fixes' I found, without success.

To sum-up, how do I actually close a div when clicking outside? (without jQuery if possible, I do not know the syntax at all)

Edit: added '{' after 'if' on line 14 and changed line 12 by " var x = document.getElementById(e.target.id) " as Jameel suggested. Now the e.preventDefault works on the 1st function, but that's still it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the e.target.id to the document.getElementById method like this:

```
 var x = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
```

Have you checked your javascript console for errors?

Comment: Changed the value of x as you said, and checked the console log; I had forgotten a { after if . Fixed that, and now when I click 'link' the redirect is prevented, but nothing else happens. Console now tells me "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated." [jQuery-min] (which I don't use?) and "Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated." (which I do not see in my code, can you spot where this error is coming from?)

Comment: getPreventDefault() is used by the jQuery method preventDefault().  Don't know about getUserData or setUserData 
Totally missed the { on the if - sorry.
Maybe a silly question but do you have an element with id="all" in your page or are you trying to add the eventlistener to ALL the elements?

Comment: Yeah I have a div "all" just under my <body>, at some point simply writing document.getElementById did not work, so I tried to work around it; not very clean I guess, but it does work if I replace my function with "alert(x);"

Comment: My console only returns warnings, no errors. If I replace 'preventDefault()' by 'defaultPrevented()' like the console seems to suggest, it doesn't work (my link is still a link). Regardless I don't think preventDefault is the problem, because if I run only the 1st function, it works fine. When the 2nd listener('click') is added is when the problems start.

Comment: Have to admit my core JS is pretty rusty as I tend to just use jQuery now but why not remove the && !menuframe.contains(x) from the second event listener and instead add a third click event listener that doesn't propagate for items inside your search menu. I can see what you are trying to do but think it might be more logical to treat contained and container elements separately. The other thing you can do is put console.log() calls into your code to see what is actually happening when you click on elements.  Sorry not able to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stated question (see below) i assume your first click opens/shows a new layer. Does the new element maybe overlap the underlying (your so called outside) element so that it never receives the second click? You could try to colorize the areas to check if something overlaps, or use the debugging tools of your browser.

> To sum-up, how do I actually close a div when clicking outside?

Comment: The first click does show a new layer, by changing visibility:hidden; to visibility:visible; in the CSS. This <div> has the highest z-index so it shows over the rest, I don't know if that's what you mean by 'overlap'. The newly displayed <div> is contained within <div id="all"> (that is my whole website+margins included), though, so I thought the second function would work... was I wrong on this?

Comment: Hmm could you provide an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem? I see no issue with your js code here.

Comment: My code is kinda big (especially css) so I trimmed it to just show the structure of the document, and CSS of "menuframe" [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xTV3/) . All my JS is between <script></script> elements, is it really bad? The first function by herself works fine. Tell me if it helps or if I should add more info